# Highstock Highchart empty space between chart and scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

[image]

I am having an issue with a chart as seen from image above.

For some reason there is an empty space between chart and scrollbar.

Chart does fill the area completely if the scrollbar is turned off.

How do I position it correctly?

Removing empty space or making chart to use all available height are both fine solutions for me.

Just in case, the chart's parameters are:

```
        chart: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            type: 'area',
            margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
            spacingBottom: 0,
            width: 250,
            height: 60,
            style: {
                overflow: 'visible'
            },
            skipClone: true,
        },


        xAxis: {
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            startOnTick: false,
            endOnTick: false,
            tickPositions: [],
            tickInterval: 1,
            max: 16
        },

        scrollbar: {
            enabled: true,
            height: 10
        },

        yAxis: {
            minorTickInterval: 1,
            endOnTick: false,
            startOnTick: false,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            tickPositions: [0],
            max: 7,
            tickInterval: 1
        },


        title: {
            text: null
        },


        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },


        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                animation: {
                    duration: 2000
                },
                lineWidth: 1,
                shadow: false,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                },
                marker: {
                    radius: 2,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            radius: 4                                                        }
                    }
                },
                fillOpacity: 0.25
            },
        },


        series: [{
            data: [1,1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,6,1,7,1,8,1,9,1,10,1,11,1,12,1,13,1,14,1,15,1,16,1]
        }]
```

Comment: try to change your chart height from chart options or post your code in jsfiddle

Comment: @UdhayTitus, I've tried and while it does make the chart bigger - it also makes empty space bigger too.

Comment: can I see your div tag of chart

Comment: @UdhayTitus, it is table cell, without any style tags. Will try to make jsfiddle later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decrease [navigator.margin](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator.margin) property.

```
navigator: {
  enabled: false,
  margin: 0
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/tL75q6wm/

Comment: I had to adjust the margin nevertheless to half of scrollbar height, but it worked.